# Removing Duplicate Data From Multiple Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The original code (stolen from here) that was designed to work on one sheet, works perfectly at finding data that is duplicate, but the modified version that I want to use with my macro with is glitching out and showing matches where none exist.. help?

Original Version:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E2,$L$1:$L$5000,0)),"OK","OptedOut")
```

Modifield for multiple sheets:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH('ALL CLIENTS'!E2,OptedOutEmails!$A$2:$A$5000,0)),"OK","OptedOut")
```

also when copying and pasting the formula keeps incrementing and I don't want it to increment ie E2 should change to E3, E4, E5,.. but the A2:A5000 range should remain constant.

Comment: try using ' ' around OptedOutEmails

Comment: I've tried your formula, but I can't find any error.  Could you provide the sample and also specify what error it is?

Answer (score 0):

Ooopppss.. I was looking at the wrong sheet. I'm sorry guys. >.<